# Finding minimum distance between two sets in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: geometry

Let $d(P,Q)$ denote the distance between two points $P$ and $Q$ in the plane.

Let $A=\left\{ (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:xy=0\right\}$ and $B=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:xy=1\right\}$.

Compute:
$$
\operatorname{inf}_{P\in A,Q\in B}\:d(P,Q).
$$

Comment: Can you draw $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Btw: if you are asking support for homework exercises, it would be nice if you could explain what you did so far and/or specify your problems

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

$$\begin{align*}\bullet&\;\;\;A\;\text{ is just both axis and $\;B\;$ is the hyperbola}\;\;y=\frac1x\\
\bullet&\;\;\;\text{Both axis are asymptotes of}\;\;y=\frac1x\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $A$ consists of the $x$ and $y$ axes, while $B $ consists of the points satisfying $y=\frac 1 x$. Note that for arbitrarily large $y$, $x = \frac 1 y$ gets arbitrarily small, thus arbitrarily close to the $y$ axis, which is contained in $A$. Thus, $\inf d(P,Q)=0$.